# Equivalent to Django and tastypie with Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

I am a Django developer moving to node.js.

I would like to implement a REST interface with a mature framework based on node.js, express and Mongoose.

Is-there an existing framework to implement a REST api with nested resource like Tastypie for Django?

Comment: Marking to close "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."